# time.sleep() is not pausing the while loop and so freeing the worker in threadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, multithreading

When this executor.submit() is called for the fourth time:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        while True:
            client_socket, client_address = server.current_socket.accept()

            client_socket.setblocking(False)

            executor.submit(server.run_client_socket, client_socket)
```

with server.run_client_socket() being:

```
    def run_client_socket(self, socket):

        if self.clients[socket]['data'].decode("utf-8") == 'Tom':
            print('Tom thread running')

        while True:
            message = self.read_message(socket)

            if message is False:
                print('time.sleep called')
                time.sleep(0.2)
                continue

            self.instantiated_logger.logger.info(
                f'Received message from {self.clients[socket]["data"].decode("utf-8")}:'
                f' {message["data"].decode("utf-8")}'
            )

            self.broadcast_messages(socket, message)
```

Despite the fact that when `server.run_client_socket()` is called for the fourth time, `self.clients[socket]['data'].decode("utf-8")` is 'Tom', `print('Tom thread running')` is not called.

My thinking was that `time.sleep(0.2)` would pause one of the other 3 threads long enough to free up one of the ThreadPoolExecutor's workers, leaving one of them (handling client 'Tom') to call `server.run_client_socket()`.

Am I missing something?

I understand that I might not have pasted all the code needed to debug this in this post, so here is a link to the server code: https://dpaste.org/o1JB

Answer (score 0):

All three threads from pool run in infinite `while True` And no one to handle the new connection because `max_workers=3`

Comment: Yes, I know. `time.sleep()` is an attempt to pause the `while True` and free that worker /thread to handle the 4th client. But it doesn't work for some reason.

My question here is why?

Comment: Sleep doesn’t free thread. Thread hangs in sleep call.

Comment: Alex do you know how I can free the thread temporarily? I am stuck.